# Passing array's through functions in c++, getting error:primary-expression before ']'

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm in a basic csci, computer programming course, and have been fiddling with this code for hours.  I'm trying to pass an array through a function, and my code will not compile.  I can't figure out what's going wrong with my code.  It is as follows:

```
int buildArray (double*);
int main ()
{
    int valuesPerLine;
    int randomValues;
    double array[110];

    srand(time(NULL));
    cout<<"How many values should be displayed per line? ";
    cin>>valuesPerLine;
    randomValues=buildArray(array[]);
    cout<<array[50];
    return (0);
}

int buildArray (double array[])
{
    int t; //t is the total number of numbers in the array
    t=rand();
    array[t];

    for (int i=0; i<t; i++)
        {
            array[i]=randDouble();
        }
    return(t);
}
```

The `cout<<array[50];` is just there for myself to see if the answer changed.  It will not be in the final code.

Is there something simple I missed?  I've usually been able to help other people with the code in class but for some reason I can't figure this one out.

Thanks for everything!
P.S.
This isn't the entire code, and I know in this case I haven't said what the randDouble is, but I don't believe that is important, because that code seems to compile fine as it is.  If it is needed, let me know and I can post it below.

Comment: use `buildArray(array)`

Comment: @Akardian Don't guess what's necessary or not, don't post additional information with follow up comments. Post a [MCVE] please, that simple.

Comment: `array[t];` has no side effects -- it is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing an array to function, you only pass the pointer to the first element of the array.

In your case, it would be:

```
randomValues = buildArray(array);
```